# How to save multiple subplots at full bit depth

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I'm using Python 2.7, OpenCV, matplotlib to create a 'contact sheet' of image transformations. My input file is ~1920x1200 16-bit grayscale PNG. I would like to save the full contact sheet (represented in code by the 'fig' object if i'm understanding correctly).

When I run the following i get a ~200kb output PNG that appears blank to image viewers. I'm not sure if i'm using savefig() correctly (or on the correct object), or if the problem is that savefig is confused by the 16-bit data

Sorry for the hacky code!

edit: sample here http://www.filedropper.com/sample_83

```
fig,axs = plt.subplots(5,3)
for clip in enumerate(range(1,6)):
    for exp in enumerate(range(2,5)):
        gridsize = (pow(2,exp[1]),pow(2,exp[1]))
        cliplim = clip[1]*3 

        clahe = cv.createCLAHE(clipLimit=cliplim,tileGridSize=gridsize)
        cl = cv.normalize(clahe.apply(img16),None,0,65535,cv.NORM_MINMAX)

        axs[clip[0],exp[0]].imshow(cv.bitwise_not(cl),cmap='Greys')

        axs[clip[0],exp[0]].set_title('clip=%s grid=%s'%(cliplim,gridsize[0]))
        axs[clip[0],exp[0]].get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
        axs[clip[0],exp[0]].get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
fig.savefig('out.png')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Kindly share the image if you would like assistance. Thank you.

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/sample_83

Answer (score 2):

Your image is indeed 16-bit, but it is low in contrast which is why it looks *"flat grey"*. You can run it through **ImageMagick** `identify` like this. I have added arrows on the right pointing to the salient parts.

```
magick identify -verbose sample.png               # omit "magick" if still using v6
```

**Sample Output**

```
Image: sample.png
  Format: PNG (Portable Network Graphics)
  Mime type: image/png
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 1920x1080+0+0
  Units: Undefined
  Colorspace: Gray
  Type: Grayscale
  Base type: Undefined
  Endianess: Undefined
  Depth: 16-bit                               <--- 16-bit
  Channel depth:
    Gray: 16-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Pixels: 2073600
    Gray:
      min: 27916  (0.425971)                  <--- min 27,916 of 65,535
      max: 44722 (0.682414)                   <--- max 44,722 of 65,535
      mean: 30629.2 (0.467372)
      standard deviation: 297.459 (0.00453893)
      kurtosis: 219.144
      skewness: 6.43389
      entropy: 0.811496
  Rendering intent: Undefined
  Gamma: 0.454545
  Matte color: grey74
  Background color: white
  Border color: srgb(223,223,223)
  Transparent color: none
  Interlace: None
  Intensity: Undefined
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 1920x1080+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: Zip
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2020-02-28T08:17:02+00:00
    date:modify: 2020-02-28T08:17:01+00:00
    png:IHDR.bit-depth-orig: 16
    png:IHDR.bit_depth: 16
    png:IHDR.color-type-orig: 0
    png:IHDR.color_type: 0 (Grayscale)
    png:IHDR.interlace_method: 0 (Not interlaced)
    png:IHDR.width,height: 1920, 1080
    signature: bfd36a4055d8bb31695bbed19738063efd9e842d4beec01c5d5123d32f1df42f
  Artifacts:
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 3.96262MiB
  Number pixels: 2073600
  Pixels per second: 75.0272MP
  User time: 0.020u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.027
  Version: ImageMagick 7.0.9-6 Q16 x86_64 2019-11-27 https://imagemagick.org
```

As you can see, the brightness ranges from 27,916 to 44,722 out of a possible range of 65,535 so you are using just 26% of the available range in a 16-bit image.

So, if you want your image to show up better, you may want normalise it to full-range first.